# How can I add custom view in android status bar?

Tags: java, android, notifications, overlay, android-statusbar

I am creating a chat app, and I want to add a view like textview or a progressbar in android system's status bar for the app like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rq0L2.jpg)

I don't know what to do for this. I also searched in google for a solution, but they giving result for **Notification**.

Here I mention that, **I'm not asking for any notification or floating view!** I just want to add a view in that status bar.

Can anyone help me to do this?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

As an app developer, you have no permission to set a view inside the status bar. Only the Android OS itself can manage and change views in the status bar according to the current state of the device (what notifications it has, battery status etc.)

As a developer, you can only:

1. [Hide it](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status)
2. [Change its color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android)

What are you trying to achieve? Surely Android has a better solution to your problem.

Comment: So, how they do this? ' https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rq0L2.jpg ' ?? I want to do something like this!

Comment: I guess that they hide the status bar, make the top part of the layout transparent and then they can virtually "draw" on the location of the status bar. Check out this library that does something similar: https://github.com/fede87/StatusBarAlert

Comment: Yup , it's that. I was asking for this!! Thanks <3

Comment: Is there any library for java? I don't know kotlin well!

Comment: Not that I could find. Good opportunity to learn Kotlin :)