# (android) Why does the style of the theme only partially apply?

Tags: android, toolbar, android-theme, android-statusbar

I want to know why the theme's style is only partially applied.

I set the basic theme as `NoActionBar`.

And I made a new toolbar using `CoordinatorLayout`, `AppBarLayout`, and `Toolbar` in `Main.xml`.

I also defined New theme style for this toolbar and changed `stauts bar` color and applied this theme.

But it doesn't work. However, when i changed stauts bar color defined in `BaseTheme`.

It worked well. I'm so confused.

I clearly applied the `theme style` I defined. But the `BaseTheme's status bar color` still applies.

When i changed `Toolbar` color, It was applied well.

I don't know the reason.

Was the My Custom Toolbar affected by `Manifest's Theme'?

Please tell me why..

Main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppBarOverlay">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/black"
                app:titleMarginStart="30dp"
                android:paddingRight="30dp"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.PopupOverlay"/>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.WriteWeight" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/light_green</item>

        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">@color/light_green_dark</item> <!-- not apply -->
<!--        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/light_green_dark</item> ///////////////// not apply -->
<!--        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/light_green_dark</item>    ///////////////// not apply -->
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/light_green</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/light_green_dark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/light_green_dark</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.writeweight">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.WriteWeight">
        <activity android:name=".data.DailyRecordDetailActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView rcv_dailyRecord;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

    DailyRecordAdapter dailyRecordAdapter;
    ArrayList<DailyRecordModel> dailRecordItems;

    final static String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rcv_dailyRecord = findViewById(R.id.rcv_dailyrecord);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
//        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
//        toolbar.setTitle("목 록");
```

Comment: can you tell how do you set the actionbar in your behavior (java/kotlin)

Comment: You mean in Code?

Comment: you removed the action bar from the app's theme .. do you already set it in java?

Comment: I just modified the writing. please Look at the code.

Comment: I already set `toolbar` using `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`

Comment: thanks for sharing.. do you mean that the `toolbar` takes `light_green` color instead of `light_green_dark` ? is this your problem ?

Comment: No..That's just the color I chose..
My problem is that the color of `Theme.AppBarOverlay` (status bar color) does not apply in Main.xml's theme..Only `Theme.WriteWeight` color is applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a customized `Theme.AppBarOverlay` style in styles.xml. Now this style is useless unless you apply it to a certain view/widget.

**The first point:**

Applying a style to a particular view, doesn't affect other views/widgets.

Looking at your layout to see which view you set this style to: it's the `AppBarLayout` widget.

the `AppBarLayout` area doesn't include the status bar area, that is because the status bar is android system component, not activity widget (not part of your activity). So, when applying this style to `AppBarLayout`, it can only apply the attributes of this style on the area that this  `AppBarLayout` view occupies on your screen.

**The second point:**

Each view/widget has certain attributes that can affect its style; not only there are common attributes that can be applied to any view; but also there are other unique attributes that are specific to certain views. Applying style attributes to views that can't utilize them won't have affect on those views, or they can have unexpected behavior on those views.

**Applying both points in your example:**

You used `android:statusBarColor` attribute which can be applied to system/status bar, and added it to the style that is applied to `AppBarLayout`; so this style can only be applied to the `AppBarLayout` surrounding area, i.e. not the status bar itself (point 1), and also the `AppBarLayout` won't utilize it as it won't affect anything in its layout because it's not a part of attributes that can affect `AppBarLayout` (point 2).

The status bar is a system component, not app/activity component/widget, so changing it must be in the global theme of your app, or you can change it programmatically.

You can have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android) for more info.

Comment: Wow.. Thank you. I'm sorry, but can I ask you a few questions?
1.You say `AppBarLayout` Surrounding area, I don't understand exactly what this means.This means only `AppBarLayout`? Or  both `AppBarLayout` , `Toolbar` based on my code


2.I didn't quite understand the meaning of the second point of the example.(From `and aloso` ~~~~~ )
(I tried to understand your answer, but I am not good at English. sorry..)


3. gloabal theme means `Theme.WriteWeight`  in `themes.xml` and is aplied `Manifest.xml`?

Comment: @ybybyb Yeah you are right. it's `AppBarLayout` including any inner view of it .. like in your case the `Toolbar` ... I mean by its surrounding frame i.e its width/height sorry if this wasn't that descriptive ... but make sure that inner view attributes overrides their parent views .. i.e. the attributes in `Toolbar` overrides the same/similar attributes in its parent `AppBarLayout` .. for instance if you use `android:background="@android:color/black"` in the `Toolbar`, then the overall color you'll see is the `Toolbar` black color not the `AppBarLayout` color set in the style

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand it.
However, I didn't understand one more thing yet.
In your answer, in the computer `Applying both points in your example:`,
I didn't understand well about `point 2` (From and also~ AppBarLayout).
Can you explain it more easily? Sorry..

Comment: I mean that `AppBarLayout` has attribute set that can affect its look and behavior.... if you add an attribute (that is not a part of this set) to the `AppBarLayout` then this attribute can either has no effect on the look of the `AppBarLayout` or it can have an unexpected behavior on it (because this specific attribute is not related to `AppBarLayout` set of attributes... in your example you put `android:statusBarColor` to the `AppBarLayout`.. but actually this attribute doesn't belong to `AppBarLayout` attribute set, but it belongs to the status bar (i.e. it can only affects the status bar)

Comment: I finally understood. 
If so, according to your answer, do I have to change the color of the status bar from the global theme (i.e. `Theme.WriteWeight` in `themes.xml`)?

Comment: yes or you can change it programmatically in java if you wish .. plz check link down in the answer

Comment: Thank you so much..! Happy New Year.. :)