# how to change statusbar color in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

how to make status bar color transparent in compose like here:

[image]

it has the same color but with a little bit shade.

Comment: Any way to implement a gradient yet?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Google has just created a library called `accompanist`.
You can find it here: https://github.com/google/accompanist

It contains multiple helpful libraries for Jetpack Compose, among which is a System UI Controller that you can use for changing the status bar color.

**Docs** - https://google.github.io/accompanist/systemuicontroller/

Comment: This library is not helpful for coloring the bars any more

Comment: Why is that a thing?

Comment: @ArthurKhazbs so what should we use instead?

Comment: @MohammadBaqer I think [`androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsControllerCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/WindowInsetsControllerCompat) should do it. Take a look at this [`Theme.kt`](https://gist.github.com/Khazbs/1f1f1b5c05f45dbfa465f249b1e20506) snippet as a template/example.

Comment: @MohammadBaqer Oh, of course, forgot to mention the main darn thing: [`android.view.Window.setStatusBarColor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window#setStatusBarColor(int)) and [`android.view.Window.setNavigationBarColor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window#setNavigationBarColor(int))

Answer (score 113):

> Step 1 (add dependency)  =>  version may change

```
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.27.0"
```

> Step 2 => inside Theme.kt file
>
> change the colors according to your need in the functions below.

```
val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
if(darkTheme){
    systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(
        color = Color.Transparent
    )
}else{
    systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(
        color = Color.White
    )
}
```

> Step 3 => ON **systemUiController** you can access all types of customizations you need for your app. Above is a sample for **setSystemBarsColor**

Comment: You can also use systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(color = Color.White) , if you only want to change status bar color

Comment: Be aware the code in `SideEffect` section (in `theme.kt`) can modify the behavior, as the default compose project template does.

Comment: For the if statement, you can key off of `isSystemInDarkTheme()`

Comment: after adding this library preview stopped working and then removing again preview worked.

Comment: What is the difference between SystemBars and StatusBar??

Comment: Apparently there is some issue with accompanist. It works and set color only if I am coming back to that screen, not in the first go

Comment: @Arst I think system bar is interchangeable with status bar, see also https://m2.material.io/design/platform-guidance/android-bars.html

Comment: This library is now deprecated.

Answer (score 19):

I think other answers are overthinking - unless you really want to change the status bar colour dynamically in the source code.

Just check out your src/main/res/values-night/themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.HelloWorld" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        ...
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/black</item>
        ...

        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: You can change or add colors in `src/main/res/values/colors.xml` and then use them  in `src/main/res/values/themes.xml` 

If you add a color in colors.xml:  `<color name='orangePlain'>#FFff5a00</color>` you can then change it in themes.xml  `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/orangePlain</item>`

Comment: This is not really a great solution for compose if you want to change it for different screens.

Comment: "unless you really want to change the status bar colour dynamically in the source code"

Answer (score 17):

Just go for the old-fashioned way and add this to themes.xml:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Comment: with compose there is no theme.xml

Comment: @Carmen There is you can still use the XML themes but you will have more than one source of truth

Comment: This is close, but with whiteish themes, the statusbar icons stay white.

Comment: Adding `<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>` seemed to do the correct icon colors for both light and dark themes.

Answer (score 17):

Here's my solution without accompanist and pretty minimal. All is done in the Theme definition. This is the standard code that comes out if you create a new compose project, but with the block in the middle added:

```
@Composable
fun JtxBoardTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }
        darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }

    val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val activity  = view.context as Activity
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                activity.window.navigationBarColor = colorScheme.primary.copy(alpha = 0.08f).compositeOver(colorScheme.surface.copy()).toArgb()
                activity.window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.background.toArgb()
                WindowCompat.getInsetsController(activity.window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = !darkTheme
                WindowCompat.getInsetsController(activity.window, view).isAppearanceLightNavigationBars = !darkTheme
            }
        }
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}
```

I am applying a color on the status and navigation bar. The color for the navigation bar is calculated as I would like to use the same color as the bottom app bar (which has an elevation of 2 which means a color overlay of the primary color of 8%).

```
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(activity.window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = !darkTheme
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(activity.window, view).isAppearanceLightNavigationBars = !darkTheme
```

Those two lines takes care of the icons in the navigation and status bar. As
WindowCompat.getInsetsController(activity.window, view).isAppearanceLightNavigationBars = !darkTheme
is only available from Android API level 26 (O), I have limited the whole block to this version. If you only want a color for the status bar, then you could also go to min API level 23 (M).

I am not happy with the way how I calculate the color for the navigation bar, but it was the best way that worked also with dynamic colors.

Comment: Why are you wrapping everything inside that `if` check for the android version when you can only put that line for navigation inside the `if`?

Comment: @yamin I wanted to either set both (navigationBarColor AND statusBarColor) or keep the standard colors for both bars for older Android versions. But I guess this is a matter of taste. For sure you could also just put the one technically relevant line in the if check for the version code.

Answer (score 13):

I use this code, which I found in the Jetpack Compose samples. It works fine for me. Just tweak to your own liking.

```
@Composable
fun SystemUi(windows: Window) =
    MaterialTheme {
        windows.statusBarColor = MaterialTheme.colors.surface.toArgb()
        windows.navigationBarColor = MaterialTheme.colors.surface.toArgb()

        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        if (MaterialTheme.colors.surface.luminance() > 0.5f) {
            windows.decorView.systemUiVisibility = windows.decorView.systemUiVisibility or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
        }

        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        if (MaterialTheme.colors.surface.luminance() > 0.5f) {
            windows.decorView.systemUiVisibility = windows.decorView.systemUiVisibility or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ahh, the good old deprecation warning suppression... artisanship at its finest

Answer (score 12):

In **Jetpack material3**

Here's the **theme.kt** file that you need to modify.

[*I comment that out where you need to make changes*]

```
@Composable
fun WellnessTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
      dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
        val context = LocalContext.current
        if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
      }
      darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
      else -> LightColorScheme
    }
    val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
      SideEffect {
          val window = (view.context as Activity).window
          window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.background.toArgb() // here change the color
          window.navigationBarColor = colorScheme.background.toArgb() // here change the color

          // here change the status bar element color
          WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = !darkTheme
      }
    }

    MaterialTheme(
      colorScheme = colorScheme,
      typography = Typography,
      content = content
    )
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The simple answer is:
Head to your MainActivity.kt, then enter these codes

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
```

This comes before

```
    setContent{}
```

Then head to your values folder, open colors.xml and create

```
<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

Go to themes open themes.xml and themes.xml(night) and place this code in the two files, in one of the style tags that has colors in it.

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">@color/transparent</item>
```

That is the simple way to create a transparent status bar on Android.

Comment: Using the WindowCompat caused my app to not behave correctly. I don't think it's needed, adjusting colors.xml and themes.xml is enough

Comment: Alright, but check well what you typed, because without that, when you switch from dark screen to light screen you may still not get the desired output.

Comment: You can use `@android:color/transparent` instead of declare it

Answer (score 9):

If you're not interested in using the `accompanist` library, you can write this code into your `composable` function:

```
val activity = LocalView.current.context as Activity
val backgroundArgb = MaterialTheme.colors.background.toArgb()
activity.window.statusBarColor = backgroundArgb
```

Also, for changing status bar icon color you can do like this:

```
val wic = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)
wic.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = false // Adapt it with your implementation
```

Answer (score 7):

Slight modification of [@Patrik Lang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72776074/8229399), you can use this inside any `@Composable` functions:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun StatusBarColor(color: Color) {
    val view = LocalView.current
    val darkTheme = isSystemInDarkTheme()

    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            window.statusBarColor = color.toArgb()
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = !darkTheme
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightNavigationBars = !darkTheme
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your Theme use this to change status bar color

```
val view = LocalView.current
if (!view.isInEditMode) {
    SideEffect {
        val window = (view.context as Activity).window
        window.statusBarColor = if (darkTheme)  Color.Black.toArgb() else Purple40.toArgb()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how I approached this case:

I used the surface color for the status bar color, then added the not (**!**) at the **darkTheme** variable, so as to make the status bar icons visible in cases of light and dark theme.

```
val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            window?.statusBarColor =
                colorScheme.surface.toArgb() // surface becomes the the status bar color

            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars =
                !darkTheme // not darkTheme makes the status bar icons visible
        }
    }
```

This is my general code

```
@Composable
fun MyAppNameTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true, content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }

        darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }
    val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            window?.statusBarColor =
                colorScheme.surface.toArgb() // surface becomes the the status bar color

            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars =
                !darkTheme // not darkTheme makes the status bar icons visible
        }
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme, typography = Typography, content = content
    )
}
```

**Results:**

My app in light theme
[image: image showing light theme status bar]

My app in dark theme
[image: image showing dark theme status bar]

Answer (score 3):

The answers are really complicated :o !!!
You can change the style of the app from the style xml and that is it.
Here an example from https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/Rally

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.Rally" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/statusBarColor</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">?attr/colorSurface</item>
</style>
```

The line responsible for changing the color of the status bar here is

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/statusBarColor</item>
```

But you have also to consider the text inside the status bar. If you set the color to black for example and you don't indicate that the chosen color is dark, the text inside will be black, and thus it will be invisible. To fix that you have to set the following attribute to false if the chosen color is dark otherwise true.

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">false</item>
```

**Important Note**: Don't forget to add the theme attribute to your manifest file:

```
    <application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Rally">
```

Answer (score 3):

**Updated answer**
Google's Accompanist library collection has has some changes and the systemuicontroller library is now deprecated.

The primary use case was to make it easier to go edge-to-edge. For this use case, there is now a [direct replacement](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity#(androidx.activity.ComponentActivity).enableEdgeToEdge(androidx.activity.SystemBarStyle,androidx.activity.SystemBarStyle)): `Activity.enableEdgeToEdge`

Keep the following in mind when using it:

> The default style configures the system bars with a transparent background when contrast can be enforced by the system (API 29 or above).

To solve the problem post-deprecation, place this in your calling activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    enableEdgeToEdge()
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Open your Theme.kt and change the base code to this:

```
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.background.toArgb()
            val wic = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view)
            wic.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = !darkTheme
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use this code (e.g. in your `ui.theme.Theme` file):

```
SideEffect {
    val window = (view.context as Activity).window
    window.statusBarColor = YOUR_COLOR.toArgb()
}
```

It is template code from official Android Studio composable example.

Answer (score 2):

Editing the Theme.kt file and making changes to these lines is a straightforward process.

```
if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.background.toArgb()
            window.navigationBarColor = colorScheme.background.toArgb()
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = !darkTheme
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22192691/9957384

It works but maybe there is a better solution in compose.
For convenience, I suggest creating an Ambient

Comment: That solution is for changing the app bar and NOT the device's status bar.

Answer (score 1):

use the new Activity.enableEdgeToEdge method available in androidx.activity 1.8.0-alpha03 and later

```
enableEdgeToEdge(
            statusBarStyle = SystemBarStyle.auto(TRANSPARENT, TRANSPARENT),
            navigationBarStyle = SystemBarStyle.auto(TRANSPARENT, TRANSPARENT)
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make the screen edge to edge:

Follow this guide: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/insets

2. As an alternative to the deprecated Google accopanist library, you can use this composable extension (modified from the Google library):

```
@Composable
fun rememberWindowInsetController(
    window: Window? = findWindow(),
): WindowInsetsControllerCompat? {
    val view = LocalView.current
    return remember(view, window) {
        window?.let {
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(it, view)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun findWindow(): Window? =
    (LocalView.current.parent as? DialogWindowProvider)?.window
        ?: LocalView.current.context.findWindow()

private tailrec fun Context.findWindow(): Window? =
    when (this) {
        is Activity -> window
        is ContextWrapper -> baseContext.findWindow()
        else -> null
    }
```

3. Then with a copy of WindowInsetsController, you can set the status bar color to light:

```
val windowInsetsController = rememberWindowInsetController()
windowInsetsController?.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = true
```

4. Finally, the part of making the translucent bar is just place a translucent retangle of the size of the insets on the very top of your UI, behind the status bar icons:

```
    val systemBarHeight = WindowInsets.systemBars.getTop(LocalDensity.current).dp
    Spacer(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(systemBarHeight)
            .background(Color.Gray.copy(alpha = 0.5f))
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

**This does the job**

**It works like a charm. Trust me**

You can check the whole project here `https://github.com/samuel23taku/WeatherApp`

```
// Material 3
package com.example.weatherapp_jetpack_compose.ui.theme
import android.app.Activity
import androidx.compose.foundation.isSystemInDarkTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.lightColorScheme
import androidx.compose.material3.darkColorScheme
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.toArgb
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalView
import androidx.core.view.WindowCompat


    private val LightColors = lightColorScheme(
        primary = md_theme_light_primary,
        onPrimary = md_theme_light_onPrimary,
        primaryContainer = md_theme_light_primaryContainer,
        onPrimaryContainer = md_theme_light_onPrimaryContainer,
        secondary = md_theme_light_secondary,
        onSecondary = md_theme_light_onSecondary,
        secondaryContainer = md_theme_light_secondaryContainer,
        onSecondaryContainer = md_theme_light_onSecondaryContainer,
        tertiary = md_theme_light_tertiary,
        onTertiary = md_theme_light_onTertiary,
        tertiaryContainer = md_theme_light_tertiaryContainer,
        onTertiaryContainer = md_theme_light_onTertiaryContainer,
        error = md_theme_light_error,
        errorContainer = md_theme_light_errorContainer,
        onError = md_theme_light_onError,
        onErrorContainer = md_theme_light_onErrorContainer,
        background = md_theme_light_background,
        onBackground = md_theme_light_onBackground,
        surface = md_theme_light_surface,
        onSurface = md_theme_light_onSurface,
        surfaceVariant = md_theme_light_surfaceVariant,
        onSurfaceVariant = md_theme_light_onSurfaceVariant,
        outline = md_theme_light_outline,
        inverseOnSurface = md_theme_light_inverseOnSurface,
        inverseSurface = md_theme_light_inverseSurface,
        inversePrimary = md_theme_light_inversePrimary,
        surfaceTint = md_theme_light_surfaceTint,
        outlineVariant = md_theme_light_outlineVariant,
        scrim = md_theme_light_scrim,
    )


    private val DarkColors = darkColorScheme(
        primary = md_theme_dark_primary,
        onPrimary = md_theme_dark_onPrimary,
        primaryContainer = md_theme_dark_primaryContainer,
        onPrimaryContainer = md_theme_dark_onPrimaryContainer,
        secondary = md_theme_dark_secondary,
        onSecondary = md_theme_dark_onSecondary,
        secondaryContainer = md_theme_dark_secondaryContainer,
        onSecondaryContainer = md_theme_dark_onSecondaryContainer,
        tertiary = md_theme_dark_tertiary,
        onTertiary = md_theme_dark_onTertiary,
        tertiaryContainer = md_theme_dark_tertiaryContainer,
        onTertiaryContainer = md_theme_dark_onTertiaryContainer,
        error = md_theme_dark_error,
        errorContainer = md_theme_dark_errorContainer,
        onError = md_theme_dark_onError,
        onErrorContainer = md_theme_dark_onErrorContainer,
        background = md_theme_dark_background,
        onBackground = md_theme_dark_onBackground,
        surface = md_theme_dark_surface,
        onSurface = md_theme_dark_onSurface,
        surfaceVariant = md_theme_dark_surfaceVariant,
        onSurfaceVariant = md_theme_dark_onSurfaceVariant,
        outline = md_theme_dark_outline,
        inverseOnSurface = md_theme_dark_inverseOnSurface,
        inverseSurface = md_theme_dark_inverseSurface,
        inversePrimary = md_theme_dark_inversePrimary,
        surfaceTint = md_theme_dark_surfaceTint,
        outlineVariant = md_theme_dark_outlineVariant,
        scrim = md_theme_dark_scrim,
    )

    @Composable
    fun JetpackWeatherTheme(
        useDarkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
        content: @Composable() () -> Unit
    ) {

        val colors = if (!useDarkTheme) {
            LightColors
        } else {
            DarkColors
        }
        val activity = LocalView.current.context as Activity
        val backgroundArgb = colors.background.toArgb()
        activity.window?.statusBarColor = backgroundArgb

        val wic = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(activity.window, activity.window.decorView)
        wic.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = !useDarkTheme
        MaterialTheme(
            colorScheme = colors,
            content = content
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Donny Rozendal gave best answer. Just to be clear :

```
implementation("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.30.1")
```

Theme.kt

```
@Composable
fun OneProjTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()

    DisposableEffect(systemUiController, darkTheme){
        systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor( color = Color.Transparent, darkIcons = darkTheme)
        //systemUiController.setStatusBarColor(color = Color., darkIcons = darkTheme)
        systemUiController.setNavigationBarColor(color = Color.Transparent, darkIcons = darkTheme)

        onDispose {  }
    }
```

Activity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
```

Comment: Disposable Effect with empty onDispose call. U shouldn't be using this Effect type.

Answer (score 0):

Change the color scheme in ui.theme folder > color.kt file, ex: val Purple80 = Color(0xFF495E57)

"primary" is responsible for status bar color which is in theme.kt file under ui.theme

Answer (score -3):

```
   def version = "0.4.1"
implementation "dev.chrisbanes.accompanist:accompanist-coil:$version"
implementation "dev.chrisbanes.accompanist:accompanist-insets:$version"


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
    setContent {
        // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
        val systemUiController = remember { SystemUiController(window) }
        Providers(SysUiController provides systemUiController) {
            ProvideWindowInsets {
                val sysUiController = SysUiController.current

                onCommit(sysUiController, LightColorPalette2.uiBackground) {
                    sysUiController.setSystemBarsColor(
                        color = LightColorPalette2.uiBackground.copy(alpha = AlphaNearOpaque)
                    )
                }
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

and you also need this file:

```
package com.example.myjetsnack
```

import android.os.Build
import android.view.View
import android.view.Window
import androidx.compose.runtime.staticAmbientOf
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.compositeOver
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.luminance
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.toArgb

interface SystemUiController {
fun setStatusBarColor(
color: Color,
darkIcons: Boolean = color.luminance() > 0.5f,
transformColorForLightContent: (Color) -> Color = BlackScrimmed
)

```
fun setNavigationBarColor(
    color: Color,
    darkIcons: Boolean = color.luminance() > 0.5f,
    transformColorForLightContent: (Color) -> Color = BlackScrimmed
)

fun setSystemBarsColor(
    color: Color,
    darkIcons: Boolean = color.luminance() > 0.5f,
    transformColorForLightContent: (Color) -> Color = BlackScrimmed
)
```

}

fun SystemUiController(window: Window): SystemUiController {
return SystemUiControllerImpl(window)
}

/**

- A helper class for setting the navigation and status bar colors for a [Window], gracefully
- degrading behavior based upon API level.
  */
  private class SystemUiControllerImpl(private val window: Window) : SystemUiController {

  /**

  - Set the status bar color.
  - 
  - @param color The **desired** [Color] to set. This may require modification if running on an
  - API level that only supports white status bar icons.
  - @param darkIcons Whether dark status bar icons would be preferable. Only available on
  - API 23+.
  - @param transformColorForLightContent A lambda which will be invoked to transform [color] if
  - dark icons were requested but are not available. Defaults to applying a black scrim.
    */
    override fun setStatusBarColor(
    color: Color,
    darkIcons: Boolean,
    transformColorForLightContent: (Color) -> Color
    ) {
    val statusBarColor = when {
    darkIcons && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23 -> transformColorForLightContent(color)
    else -> color
    }
    window.statusBarColor = statusBarColor.toArgb()

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    if (darkIcons) {
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = window.decorView.systemUiVisibility or
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
    } else {
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = window.decorView.systemUiVisibility and
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR.inv()
    }
    }
    }

  /**

  - Set the navigation bar color.
  - 
  - @param color The **desired** [Color] to set. This may require modification if running on an
  - API level that only supports white navigation bar icons. Additionally this will be ignored
  - and [Color.Transparent] will be used on API 29+ where gesture navigation is preferred or the
  - system UI automatically applies background protection in other navigation modes.
  - @param darkIcons Whether dark navigation bar icons would be preferable. Only available on
  - API 26+.
  - @param transformColorForLightContent A lambda which will be invoked to transform [color] if
  - dark icons were requested but are not available. Defaults to applying a black scrim.
    */
    override fun setNavigationBarColor(
    color: Color,
    darkIcons: Boolean,
    transformColorForLightContent: (Color) -> Color
    ) {
    val navBarColor = when {
    Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29 -> Color.Transparent // For gesture nav
    darkIcons && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 26 -> transformColorForLightContent(color)
    else -> color
    }
    window.navigationBarColor = navBarColor.toArgb()

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    if (darkIcons) {
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = window.decorView.systemUiVisibility or
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR
    } else {
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = window.decorView.systemUiVisibility and
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR.inv()
    }
    }
    }

  /**

  - Set the status and navigation bars to [color].
  - 
  - @see setStatusBarColor
  - @see setNavigationBarColor
    */
    override fun setSystemBarsColor(
    color: Color,
    darkIcons: Boolean,
    transformColorForLightContent: (Color) -> Color
    ) {
    setStatusBarColor(color, darkIcons, transformColorForLightContent)
    setNavigationBarColor(color, darkIcons, transformColorForLightContent)
    }
    }

/**

- An [androidx.compose.runtime.Ambient] holding the current [SysUiController]. Defaults to a
- no-op controller; consumers should [provide][androidx.compose.runtime.Providers] a real one.
  */
  val SysUiController = staticAmbientOf {
  FakeSystemUiController
  }

private val BlackScrim = Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0.2f) // 20% opaque black
private val BlackScrimmed: (Color) -> Color = { original ->
BlackScrim.compositeOver(original)
}

/**

- A fake implementation, useful as a default or used in Previews.
  */
  private object FakeSystemUiController : SystemUiController {
  override fun setStatusBarColor(
  color: Color,
  darkIcons: Boolean,
  transformColorForLightContent: (Color) -> Color
  ) = Unit

  override fun setNavigationBarColor(
  color: Color,
  darkIcons: Boolean,
  transformColorForLightContent: (Color) -> Color
  ) = Unit

  override fun setSystemBarsColor(
  color: Color,
  darkIcons: Boolean,
  transformColorForLightContent: (Color) -> Color
  ) = Unit
  }

Comment: Please reformat your answer and reduce it to a minimal working example