# Jetpack Compose status bar color not updated in Dark Theme

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to set different colors for dark theme and light theme. Everything works fine except status bar color.

In dark theme -> my status bar color not updated.

My theme :

```
private val DarkColorPalette = darkColors(
    primary = Color.Black,
    primaryVariant = Color.Black,
    secondary = Color.LightGray
)

private val LightColorPalette = lightColors(
    primary = Purple500,
    primaryVariant = Purple700,
    secondary = Teal200
)
```

My output in Dark theme:

[image]

Edit:

I already saw this answer - [how to change statusbar color in jetpack compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65610216/how-to-change-statusbar-color-in-jetpack-compose)

They recommend to use the library. I don't want to use any 3rd party library.

Edit 2:

my manifest file

```
   <activity
        android:name=".ActivityTextStyles"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ComposeText.NoActionBar" />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change statusbar color in jetpack compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65610216/how-to-change-statusbar-color-in-jetpack-compose)

Comment: @PhilipDukhov they recommend 3rd party library. For status bar color alone I need to use library ??

Comment: Yes, it's made by google too. They just decided that it shouldn't be inside compose itself for some reasons.

Comment: What's your Activity `Theme`?

Comment: @BartekLipinski I use MaterialTheme in my activity

Comment: So you use the default theme from sdk or are you overriding it in the `themes.xml`?

Comment: @BartekLipinski I am using default theme.

Comment: Can you show your Manifest?

Comment: @BartekLipinski I updated my Manifest code in my question. can you verify?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to set status bar color with this one line code in onCreate()

```
  this.window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.black)
```

My code:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
      
            this.window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.black)
            //your composables
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's what I discovered when I faced this same issue and decided to look deeper for the cause.

Turns out, out of the box, my Compose project reads the value for status bar color from the **themes.xml** file in **res/values**. The value is set using **colorPrimaryVariant**. Updating that value to a new color changed the color of the status bar.

Overall, I will recommend updating the values of themes.xml and colors.xml to the custom colors you wish to use for your project.

Comment: good catch. I will try

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the color of the top bar was the only one overwritten in the `themes.xml` file generated when creating the project in Android Studio.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/purple_700</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

It can be modified there.

Answer (score 1):

I have this solution which works on any version, just by editing `Theme.tk` file.

You can find `Theme.tk` file at the following address `YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/ui/theme/Theme.kt`

You will see a compose function like below **[also descriptions are commented in the below box]**

```
@Composable fun TodoAppTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(), /* === `darkTheme` is TRUE if device DarkMode is ON, FALSE if it is OFF === */
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit ) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }
        darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }
    val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            /* === Default code, must comment or remove this line === */ // window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb()
            /* === Our solution === */ window.statusBarColor = if(darkTheme) Color.Red.toArgb() else Color.BLUE.toArgb()
            /* ==============================
             Status Bar Color will be Red in DarkMode and Blue in LightMode.
                   you can replace your own colors insteaded.
                   
             Note, `colorScheme` variable gets ColorScheme based on device Light/Dark Mode 
                    in beginnings lines of this function.
                    We just set Status Bar Color directly
             ============================== */
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme
        }
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
    }
```

I hope this solution may helps