# How can I change the color of the status bar? (Android and IOS)

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, android-statusbar, ios-statusbar

Sorry for the big picture.

I did some research, including here on the stackoverflow, but I was not successful with the options I found.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=statusbar+color+%5Bxamarin.forms%5D

Answer (score 0):

In styles.xml add following line in theme

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

Answer (score -1):

[** CHANGE THE COLOR OF THE STATUS BAR**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android)

** REMOVE THE STATUS BAR COLOR**

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```