# Set android splash screen default system navigation and status bars colors for Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-layout, splash-screen

I'm using a certain color as my android app splash screen background and I want the system navigation bar and status bar to match that color immediately / by default.

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/background</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/background</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
         This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
         Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
         running.
         This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/background</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="background">#1a1a2e</color>
</resources>
```

launch_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/background" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/launch_image" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @CeltK.B. I'm trying to make the colors of the system navigation bar and status bar match the color of the splash screen when the app is launching and this code is what I have tried to do. But it's not working. So what should I do?!

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for which platform you are developing but normally, if you want to change the color of the status bar on Android, you can just put this in the first build of you app (you don't have to use green):

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  statusBarColor: Colors.green,
```

This is what I do for Android and it works.

Comment: I know about this. I wanted to do it natively using XML.

Comment: Read this, I think, it can help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android