# Android status bar color does not change from white

Tags: android, react-native, statusbar

On my app, most of the app has a backgroundColor set to white, so, I want to set my statusbar to black, according to the documentation this should work:

```
<StatusBar barStyle={'dark-content'} translucent={true} />
```

but as you can see in the image: [image: statusbar white]

now if I just put a green background to check the statusbar I get this:
[image]

What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Here are your answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the backgroundColor prop and change the color u need,
:)

```
   <StatusBar backgroundColor="#000000" barStyle="light-content"  />
```

Comment: Thanks, but already tried, the font color is not changing

Comment: I've updated the answer @DanielDöbereiner, u just need to change the bar style from "dark-content" to "light-content" to change the font color.

Comment: the problem is either with dark-content and light-content the font color is white, I need it in black

Answer (score 0):

Putting

```
 <StatusBar backgroundColor="#000000" barStyle="light-content"  />
```

worked for me