# Android Studio - Change app status bar to custom color?

Tags: android, xml

I know that you can change the status bar color in Android's themes.xml file with the following line:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">@color/teal_200</item>
```

That being said, if I want to customize the color (ie. make it a hex value), how can I do this?

Comment: I hope the information in this link can help you. [How to change the status bar color in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own custom colors in a `colors.xml` file in your res/values directory.

In `colors.xml` you can do something like the following with your preferred hex value:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="custom_color">#FF3A52B2</color>
</resources>
```

And in your `themes.xml` file you can then reference that custom color as follows:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">@color/custom_color</item>
```