# How to make the statusbar black (default) in android?

Tags: android

One of my activities has suddenly changed its color in the statusbar. By default it's black, but now it's transparent, why?

[I've marked around the bar with a circle. By default this is black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQUat.png)

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:id="@+id/do2get"
    android:src="@drawable/loading"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminateTint="#00796b"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/do2get"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Check the activity's Theme in the manifest file..

Comment: I've put it as `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >` but I want the start at the top of the screen (with the clock and WIFI signal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its all about your actitiy`s theme.
First of all check this links:

[How to change the status bar color in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android)

[How to change the background color of android status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044970/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-android-status-bar)

Maybe your base theme has attribute "android:windowTranslucentStatus" = true or "colorPrimaryDark = @android:color/transparent" etc. So you need to create new one style like:

```
<style name="YourActivityTheme" parent="BaseAppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

and then set this style to current activity theme in AndroidManifest:

```
<aplication
        ....... >
            .......    

         <activity
                android:name=".chapters.home.YourNiceActivity"
                android:theme="@style/YourActivityTheme">
                <intent-filter>
                   ...
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    .....
</application>
```

Comment: Thanks :) I just changed the android:statusBarColor from transparent to black